# Flex Won't Set Label Text At Runtime

Tags: apache-flex, text, label

Below is the flex code. It loads a url on start and gets XML. The XML is loaded fine and i can see the value of returnData[0].name in trace!! But when i try to assign the value to the label, the label just shows empty text...as in it has deleted my default text and replaced with nothing, rather than what is in returnData[0].name ?? If i use trace() the value of that variable is "John"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="800" height="523" maxWidth="800" maxHeight="523" initialize="httpService.send()" showStatusBar="false" backgroundColor="white" backgroundAlpha="0">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            public var returnData:ArrayCollection;

            protected function httpService_handler(event:ResultEvent):void{
                returnData = event.result.people.person;

                testlabel.text = returnData[0].name;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:HTTPService id="httpService" url="MYURL TO LOAD XML HERE" result="httpService_handler(event)" />
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:BorderContainer borderVisible="false" mouseDown="nativeWindow.startMove();" skinClass="MainStyle" width="800" height="600" id="container" >
        <s:Label text="Original Text" id="testlabel"/>
    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Here is the skin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("spark.components.BorderContainer")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <!-- states -->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="disabled" />
        <s:State name="normal" />
    </s:states>

    <!-- SkinParts
    name=contentGroup, type=spark.components.Group, required=false
    -->
    <s:Group id="container">
        <s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('/School Catchup/libs/images/App-BG8.png')" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" width="800" height="523" />
    </s:Group>
</s:Skin>
```

If i take the skinClass off it works i can see the text, but its almost as though the image ends up sitting on top of the label..

Comment: Your skin lacks a `contentGroup` component, hence its nested elements will not be displayed.

Comment: Is it happening to only one xml element? or all? when debugging, do you see the xml in the event.result property? try to cast like this var xml:XML = XML(event.result) and then, use the xml to retrieve the data. This is implicit casting, it will force the flex client to cast the data to the xml object.

Comment: @Zeus The data is not the problem, the skin is. However the poster never seems to answer to comments.